# mman.h does import mmap function but fails to import mremap

Tags: c, libraries, mmap

So I wanted to use the mremap function to more easily work with memory mapped files but an implicit declaration error is raised

```
addr = mremap(addr, len, len_file, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
```

I do include the required libraries, if i didnt the line

```
addr = mmap(NULL, len_file, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

would raise the same error.

My current header has the libraries that are pointed as required

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

Comment: You need to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before including any headers.

Comment: yes it was that define, thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is incorrect here:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

You must define `_GNU_SOURCE` *before* including the headers:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/mman.h>
```